# how to Read Image From a JLabel and Store in Mysql

Tags: java, mysql

I am working with On a project where I am Capturing person image and display it in a JLabel which I have managed so far but my problem is that I want to store the Image in the JLabel to MySQL database with a table with attribute blob.Can someone help please

Comment: AFAIK, we can only store the reference(s) of images in DB.

Comment: What do you mean by reference(s)?

Comment: Means - path of the file on the file system.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748/storing-images-in-db-yea-or-nay